# Less one row result when retrieve data from MSSQL on PHP

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am trying to retrieve the data from SQL Server on PHP.
However I was facing some issue here. 
The same sql query, record shown in database is 6 rows, but only shown 5 rows on PHP. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

**SQL Results**

[image: SQL]

**PHP Results**

[image: PHP]

Code

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
    $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
    $i = 1;
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        { ?>
```

Code

```
 <tr>
   <td><?php echo $i++;?></td>
 <?php foreach($row as $item ) {   ?>
<td><?=$item ?> </td>
```

Comment: URL picture => image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't output the first row of data from your server: the value of `$row` assigned in this statement

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
```

gets overwritten by this statement

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

before it gets used. You should just delete the first statement from your code i.e.

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
$i = 1;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try your foreach loop like the following.


    $html = NULL;
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $item) {
       $html .= '<td>'. $item . '</td>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';

echo $html;
```